# How do I initialize number with NaN in Borland C++?

Tags: nan, borland-c++

How do I initialize number with NaN in Borland C++?

duplicate: [Using NaN in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/235386/using-nan-in-c)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can look at `std::numeric_limits<double>::quiet_NaN()`. Include `<limits>`.

Comment: In the documentation they say "The quiet NaN for type int is:  0"... how can I discriminate between NaN and real 0?

Comment: @luvieere. Check std::numeric_limits<int>::has_quiet_NaN; You will find it is false. while std::numeric_limits<double>::has_quiet_NaN is true