# check NaN number

Tags: c++, numbers

Is it possible to check if a number is `NaN` or not?

Comment: NIL (NULL in C-ese) is a special *pointer* value.  There is no such thing as NULL for numbers.  Are you perhaps thinking of floating point NaNs?

Comment: I meant NaN, my bad, fixed the Q.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Checking if a double (or float) is NaN in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/570669/checking-if-a-double-or-float-is-nan-in-c)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Yes, by use of the fact that a `NaN` is not equal to any other number, *including itself.*

That makes sense when you think about what `NaN` means, the fact that you've created a value that isn't really within your power to represent with "normal" floating point values.

So, if you create two numbers where you don't know what they are, you can hardly consider them equal. They *may* be but, given the rather large possibility of numbers that it may be (infinite in fact), the chances that two are the same number are vanishingly small :-)

You can either look for a function (macro actually) like `isnan` (in `math.h` for C and `cmath` for C++) or just use the property that a `NaN` value is not equal to itself with something like:

```
if (myFloat != myFloat) { ... }
```

If, for some bizarre reason, your C implementation has no `isnan` (it should, since the standard mandates it), you can code your own, something like:

```
int isnan_float (float f) { return (f != f); }
```

Comment: And do wrap `myFloat != myFloat` into some sort of `isnan` function with a comment, lest future readers that don't know about it be very confused.

Answer (score 7):

Under Linux/gcc, there's **isnan(double)**, conforming to BSD4.3.

C99 provides **fpclassify(x)** and **isnan(x)**.
(But C++ standards/compilers don't necessarily include C99 functionality.)

There ought to be some way with std::numeric_limit<>...  Checking...

Doh.  I should have known...  This question has been answered before...
[Checking if a double (or float) is NaN in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/570669/checking-if-a-double-or-float-is-nan-in-c)
[Using NaN in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/235386/using-nan-in-c)
http://bytes.com/topic/c/answers/588254-how-check-double-inf-nan

Answer (score -1):

you are looking for [null](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/NULL/), but that is only useful for pointers. a number can't be null itself, it either has a known value that you put in there or random data from whatever was there in memory before.